# angularjs: Wrapping a template string with angular.element before $compile

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In Angular, I've seen people wrap a template string:

```
var template = angular.element('<div>blah</div>');
```

in angular.element() before using it in the compile service:

```
$compile(template)(scope);
```

However, $compile seems to work the same way without using angular.element():

```
var template = '<div>blah</div>';
$compile(template)(scope);
```

What's the difference between one way versus the other? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No difference.
This is from angular documentation:

**Usage**

```
$compile(element, transclude, maxPriority);
```

**Arguments**

element - `string` or `DOMElement` Element or HTML string to compile into a template function.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: Thanks for the answer!